# PHP/MySQL - How to select id from table and echo in array

Tags: php, mysql

How to make the array of **id** that we call from a table?

What I want is like this :

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // **1 - 5 select from a table**.
```

Thank you

Code :

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tableA");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query )){          
    $a = implode(',',(array)$row['id_add_user']);
    echo $a;
}
```

What I get from `echo $a` is `12345` not `1,2,3,4,5`

Comment: you mean `range` : https://eval.in/1002578

Comment: Have you got any code which selects the data from the table, there are a variety of ways to convert it to what you want depending on how you fetch the data.

Comment: I have edit my question, please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all the elements to an array, then `implode()` it into one string with your desired deliminator (here, its `", "`) once all results are fetched.

```
$result = [];
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tableA");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){          
    $result[] = $row['id_add_user']);
}

echo implode(", ", $result);
```

Comment: You are the best ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Collect necessary values into an array.

```
$a = [];
while(...){          
    $a[] = $row['id_add_user'];
}
echo implode(',', $a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `implode()` the values for each row, you need to build an array of all the values and then output the result `implode`d.  Also if you just want one column - just fetch that column in your SQL

You can further simplify it to...

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id_add_user FROM tableA");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($query );
echo implode(',',array_column($rows, 'id_add_user' ));
```

`mysqli_fetch_all` allows you to fetch all the data in one go.  Then use `array_column()` to extract the data.

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Use below SQL query for selecting the array id data

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN $array;
```

Comment: what I want is number 1,2,3,4,5 in array is come from coloumn id on tableA

Comment: This would result in `...WHERE column_name IN Array ( )`, and won't work. Try printing an array as a string and you'll see. :)